# Threaded copper fitting stripped, whats my next move?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, faucet, sink

I have an awkward plumbing problem. I am inserting a T-fitting into the flexible riser of my kitchen sink and in the process seem to have stripped the copper shank coming from the faucet. The fitting:

[image: faucet adapter]

The 1/2" nut that attaches to the shank coming from the faucet turns, but does not tighten, nor does it come off. When the water is turned on, the joint leaks. So, I think I have stripped this thread somehow.

What's my next move?

If I cut the shank, then the stripped part is still going to be stuck in the adapter fitting. Also, the shank will get shorter, and I am not confident in my ability to thread a copper tube so that it is water tight.

As you can see from the photo, it is a 1/2" to 7/8" adapter which attaches to the copper shank coming from the faucet (the corroded pipe at the top). Even though the pipe has some corrosion on it, the joint itself does not.

I have tried very forcefully to pull/twist it off, but it just turns. Does not come off.

Comment: You should take it apart first and determine what exactly was stripped.  Way easier to deal with a new braided supply line versus the male threads on the faucet itself.

Comment: @Steven The problem is I can't get it apart. The fitting turns on the shank, but it doesn't get tighter or looser.

Comment: Could you post a picture? Have you tried pulling down on the nut (hard) while you try to back it off and remove it? I think you may have to cut the nut and remove it, then check things out.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I added a photo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a standard '3/8 compression x 1/2" MIP' (male iron pipe) connector. You can get it at any hardware store.

Normal procedure is to cut the tubing above the fitting and install a new one. Your tubing does not look too good, you have to have fairly smooth tubing surface for the new compression fitting to be able to slide on and seal. You may have to cut a little farther up on the tube. Be VERY careful not to kink or bend the tube while cutting it.

[This is how compression fittings work](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u77SJgIS4mY).

You may want to purchase a [mini tubing cutter](http://www.widgetsupply.com/product/WA10.html?gclid=CKfttavS_b8CFQg0aQodkDsAMA).

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u77SJgIS4mY,

Answer (score 0):

> What's my next move?

Turn off the water supply and cut off the unservicable parts.

> I am not confident in my ability to thread a copper tube

Look for a compression fitting the right size, a replacement pipe (e.g. Monobloc-tap tailpipes are standardized where I live) or a new faucet.

You might get a more specific answer if you edit a photo into your question.

Comment: I am leaning towards the entirely-new-faucet strategy, but it seems a shame to throw out a faucet because this one joint has a problem.

Comment: @Tyler: Can you post a photo?

Comment: I added a photo